# iOS 5 TableView crashes

Tags: crash, ios5, exc-bad-access, tableview

Something got changed at the new SDK and my code suddenly isn't working.

I created a new empty project and created only a UITableView in it.
I used the same code as i've been used to, except the compiler said that i do not need to use autorelease anymore, so i removed it.

Oh, and I replaced retain with strong as i was recommended.

When I run the app it shows the TableView like it should look, but the minute i touch anywhere on screen, like scrolling for example, it crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

What do I miss??

Answer (score 0):

You should post some more informations on where your program crashed! But I don't think the mentioned compiler warnings are the reason. You should have tried to run your project with the compiler by turning of ARC (automatic reference count) and see what happens. If you can go back, do that first.

Also maybe there went something wrong with the changes you made because of ARC . If you have not done the changes with the Xcode refactoring tool I recommend you doing so.

Therefor select in the Xcode Menu:

`Edit > Refactor > Convert to Objectiv-C ARC...`

It will go through your code and apply the changes. Apple recommends though that your project should work without crashes and warnings before using it.

Comment: My project already uses ARC and I really want to learn how to use it correctly rather than just returning to the old style memory management.

Comment: these were only ideas on how to locate the error. Of course you can and should use ARC. Thats why I also wrote on how to do so